# While installing PostgreSQL on windows getting an popup "Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x64)-12.0.40660 has stopped working"

Tags: postgresql, windows-7

I am trying to install the PostgresSQL on windows7 (64-bit). I have referred the installation steps, downloaded the postgresql-9.4.12-1-windows-x64.exe file.

But when I am running this file, an popup occurs and installation gets interrupted.

getting this pop up
[image: getting this pop up]

Then I tried to install the postgresql-9.6.3-3-windows-x64.exe also but facing same error.

After searching for the solution and then I tried several ways like
"Run as administrator",
modified the file name to "postgresql-9.4.12-1-windows-x64.exe --install_runtimes 0",
installed the other visual c++ packages from microsoft support.

But still facing the same error popup.

Could someone help me to understand why I am getting this and suggest any solution for this.

Comment: Something is badly broken on your system or there's something wrong with the downloaded installer. A VC redist shouldn't fail.

Comment: any update on your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You get this message because you are on an unsupported state (Windows 7 RTM without Sp1 and any update with the version 6.1.7600.16385).

[image]

To be able to install new Visual C++ Runtimes, you need to install the [Windows 7 Sp1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=5842), next the [April Servicing Stack update and June 2016 Rollup](https://superuser.com/a/996072/174557), reboot, run Windows Update, scan for new updates and install all offered updated.

Reboot and now install `postgresql-9.4.12-1-windows-x64.exe`.

Comment: I updated the system as per your given link. But still facing same issue.

Comment: post new picture of the crash details ("Problem signature")